# Many SelectOneMenuRadio in a forEach

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a bean called Question with a lot of alternatives -->

```
 Question have 1:N Alternative.
```

I have a Page with a lot of Question, like:

```
 Page have 1:N Question
```

I need create a XHTML page showing the amount of questions and your alternatives, like this:

```
<c:forEach var="questaoCurso"
           items="#{cursandoMB.paginaAtualProva.questoesCurso}">
    <h:outputText value="#{questaoCurso.questao.texto}" />
    <br />

    <h:selectOneRadio style="font-weight: normal"
                      value="#{cursandoMB.alternativasEscolhida}" layout="pageDirection">

        <f:selectItems value="#{questaoCurso.questao.alternativasPreenchidas}"
                       var="c"
                       itemValue="#{c}"
                       itemLabel="#{c.texto}" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
    <br />
    <br />
</c:forEach>
```

The problem is that I don't know how I can set each choose alternative in a List in my ManagedBean. I can't create one variable for each Question, because this is dynamic and I don't know the amount of questions in design-time.

**SOLVED:**

I used a Map in RadioButton, see:

```
<h:selectOneRadio
            value="#{cursandoMB.alternativasEscolhidas[questaoCurso]}" converter="entityConverter" layout="pageDirection">
            <f:selectItems
                value="#{questaoCurso.questao.alternativasPreenchidas}" var="c"
                itemValue="#{c}" itemLabel="#{c.texto}" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, You must not mix render-time (e.g. f:selectItems, h:inputText ...) and build-time tags (JSTL tags, f:actionListener, ui:include ... ), for more understanding of the view build time and render time concepts and how that works please take a look to this BalusC's answer: [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

So IMO the only thing to replace is the `c:forEach` tag with `ui:repeat` like this:

```
<ui:repeat var="questaoCurso"
           value="#{cursandoMB.paginaAtualProva.questoesCurso}">
    <h:outputText value="#{questaoCurso.questao.texto}" />
    <br />

    <h:selectOneRadio style="font-weight: normal"
                      value="#{cursandoMB.alternativasEscolhida}" layout="pageDirection">

        <f:selectItems value="#{questaoCurso.questao.alternativasPreenchidas}"
                       var="c"
                       itemValue="#{c}"
                       itemLabel="#{c.texto}" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
    <br />
    <br />
</ui:repeat>
```

The `value` attribute of [ui:repeat Tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html) is:

> The name of a collection of items that this tag iterates over. The
>   collection may be a List, array, java.sql.ResultSet, or an individual
>   java Object. If the collection is null, this tag does nothing.

So you can use a `List` of Object in that `value` which in your case will be a List of Question objects, and in your Question bean you can include a `List` of answers (while `Answer` may also be a bean).

Comment: But the problem is that value attribute of SelectOneMenuRadio should be a list: value="#{cursandoMB.alternativasEscolhida}". How can i do it ?

Comment: @Shelly what do you mean by "how can i do it" ?  your variable `alternativasEscolhida` must be a List of `Question` objects ? what is the problem here ?!